# Rolling window on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am facing the following problem:
I need to calculate the slope between two points based on height and distance.

I use a rolling window of 50, with center = True. So for a certain row, the slope is calculated based on -25 indices and +25 indices. So for example, if the height at -25 (StartIndex) is 80 and the height at +25 (EndIndex) is 90 and each row represents 10 meters, then the slope would be: (90-80)/500 = 0.02

However, the height at -25 and +25 could be a NaN value. In case of a NaN value at -25, StartIndex would become -24 (and if that is also a NaN, StartIndex would become -23, et cetera). The same goes for EndIndex.

Now I created the following function and applied in on a rolling window. However, only the height is returned from the rolling window.

Hence, I want to know how I can return two columns after a rolling window, in order to do some calculations with .apply(calculate_slope).

I created this function and applied it.

```
def calculate_slope(df):
    df = df[df['Height'].notna()]

    StartIndex, EndIndex = df.iloc[0]['Height'], df.iloc[-1]['Height']
    first_KM, last_KM = df.iloc[0]['KM'], df.iloc[-1]['KM'] 

    slope = (EndIndex - StartIndex)/(last_KM - first_KM)  

    return slope
```

```
def get_slope(df, window_size=50):
    return df.assign(
        slope = lambda d: (d[['Height','KM']]
                             .rolling(window=window_size, center=True, min_periods=1)
                             .apply(calculate_slope, raw=False)
                            )
    )
```

This is the example dataframe.

```
    KM        Height
0   0.25      NaN
1   0.5       2.0
2   0.75      3.0
3   1.0       NaN
4   1.25      5.0
5   1.5       6.0
6   1.75      7.0
7   2.0       8.0
8   2.25      NaN
```

So if we set the window_size = 5, the expected result for df.iloc[4] should be:

slope = (7 - 3)/(1.75 - 0.75) = 4.0
Where 7 is `df.iloc[-1]['Height']`
3 is `df.iloc[0]['Height']`
1.75 is `df.iloc[-1]['KM']`
and 0.75 `df.iloc[0]['Height']`

However, I get an immediate error, since the dataframe after rolling window does not know 'Height'

```
KeyError: 'Height'
```

So how do I get the 'Height' and 'KM' after the rolling when apply?

Comment: Please review [mcve].  Going to be difficult to help without some sample data/desired output

Comment: This is a very simple example @user3483203 I just need to know how to access multiple columns after rolling.